# boost without libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cross-compiling

I would like to start using boost in an embedded environment. I can live without boost libraries that require compilation for quite sometime. I suppose just moving boost directory into appropriate place in our code base will do the trick

1. Am I right about it or it is more involved than that?
2. How to get rid of header files for the libraries that are not being used?
3. Are there any gcc version dependencies in boost libraries. E.g. can use gcc-4.1.1 with the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it myself, but if you compile Boost with a directory prefix, then I suppose you could move the directory later.  I can't see a big problem with that or at least one that can't be fixed quickly.

As for getting rid of header files for libraries that aren't use, look into the bcp utility for the version with which you are using:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html

It is "a tool for extracting subsets of Boost" -- exactly what you are looking for.

As for your last question, I think it depends on what version of Boost you are using.  I've never had a problem with gcc dependencies...it seems their requirements are fairly liberal.  I don't think you need to be worried too much about it unless you plan to use a version of gcc that is "much" older (than the Boost you plan to use).  I would guess 'old' here is old enough that you don't need to worry -- any number that I would say would be merely a guess...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

> Am I right about it or it is more involved than that?

That will do it.

> How to get rid of header files for the libraries that are not being used?

Why bother?  They're not going to be compiled into the program.  When you deploy your distribution won't be any different whether you remove them or not.

> Are there any gcc version dependencies in boost libraries. E.g. can use gcc-4.1.1 with the latest?

vOv - That's a very old version.  Boost takes things a lot further than most, more that I think they should most of the time, trying to make sure it works with old and/or broken compilers.  You're really pushing it though.

Comment: FYI: about using old gcc version: it is pretty common for large embedded environments delivered on a wide variety of CPUs. It takes time to verify that there are no compiler glitches in each and every CPU model being used (and it could easily count 100s of CPU models and revisions).